# Create a predefined path and fill it on user touch

Tags: android, animation, canvas, android-canvas

I need to draw a custom shape (for example a leave) path with a black stroke which will be predefined in an arraylist. What I need to do is that when user touches the screen the path will be drawn on canvas with animation. To fill the path user will touch and drag the area inside that path to fill. Only the area inside the path should be filled not the outside area.

I have gone through several websites for this but couldn't find. Anyone having idea how to implement this?